# In what way was Luke's training "incomplete"?

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi, the-empire-strikes-back

In *Star Wars Episode V: The Empire Strikes Back*, Yoda and Obi-Wan both encourage Luke to stay on Dagobah to finish his training. They beg him:

> YODA: Luke, you must complete the training.
>
> LUKE: I can’t keep the vision out of my head. They’re my friends. I’ve got to help them.
>
> YODA: You must not go.

He refuses them and leaves for Bespin to save his friends.

---

**The next time we see Yoda**, in Star Wars Episode VI: Return of the Jedi, he tells Luke that he's dying. The conversation continues:

> LUKE: But I need your help. I’ve come back to complete the training.
>
> YODA: **No more training do you require.** Already know you that which you need.
>
> LUKE: Then I am a Jedi.
>
> YODA: Oh! Not yet. One thing remains... Vader. You must confront Vader. Then, only then, a Jedi will you be.

---

If the only thing left in Luke's training is **to confront Vader**, why are Yoda and Obi-Wan so concerned with him leaving to do **exactly that**?

If he already knows "that which he needs", why wouldn't they simply drop the bomb (Vader=Anakin) and just say "go get him, good luck"?

Was there some additional training that we didn't see? Possibly after Luke returned to Dagobah but before Yoda's death?

Comment: In Empire, he's a newbie. He doesn't have his Force usage at an instinctual level.  By Jedi, he's been practising the art for three years, and has become proficient.  Maybe even worked some things out for himself.

Comment: Yoda didn't believe Luke could control himself.  By the time he comes back, it's too late (in multiple directions), and there's no point doing more.

Comment: @Tim, where does that three year figure come from?  Do we know what he was doing during that period?  In particular, do we know for sure that he didn't do any additional training with Yoda?

Comment: My understanding was always that Yoda initially doubted whether Luke could resist the call of the dark side. He wanted Luke to remain so that he could help him with specifically that (he perhaps sees that as the Jedi's collective failing with Anakin). After Luke returns, Yoda sees he is strong enough and is ready to go up against Vader (knowing what Vader/Palpatine are likely to offer him to tempt him to the dark side). The other stuff is just practice, but the call of the dark side is the true peril.

Comment: @Tim I believe that a single year separated *Empire* from *Jedi*, as ESB takes place in 3 ABY and Jedi took place in 4 ABY

Comment: During his initial time on Dagobah, Luke was learning skills, but had not yet developed the mental discipline Yoda felt was necessary to resist the Dark Side. The very fact that Luke allowed himself to be so easily drawn away to Bespin speaks to the incompleteness of his training. His initial confrontation with Vader on Bespin contributed to his overall development as a Jedi, perhaps taking the place of some of the training Yoda wanted him to receive, but gained at the risk of being turned to the Dark Side. Yoda/Obi-Wan didn't need to drop the bomb; despite his denial, Luke knew it was true.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See [Where did Luke train between ESB and RotJ](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/36187/where-did-luke-train-between-esb-and-rotj), there was actually about a year between the two films during which Luke had time to train more. It was during this time that he built his green lightsaber. By the time we see him again in *Return of the Jedi*, he seems less impulsive, more sure of himself, and stronger in the Force.

More importantly, in *Empire Strikes Back* Luke learned a couple of valuable lessons. As you mentioned, he learned the truth of Darth Vader's identity, but more importantly he learned that he couldn't solve all of his problems with a lightsaber.

Remember before entering the cave on Dagobah, Yoda told Luke to leave behind his weapons and he refused. And then Yoda told him not to face Vader and he went anyway. Later, in *Return of the Jedi* it's Yoda, not Luke, who suggests facing Vader (showing that Luke has learned humility and patience). And when the confrontation happens, Luke freely surrenders his weapon, trusting in the Force and the love of a father for his son.

It seems to me that for these reasons, Yoda changed his mind and accepted that Luke was finally ready to fulfill his destiny.

Plus, Leia was Yoda's backup plan. So he had to keep Luke alive until she escaped from Bespin. After that, it didn't matter as much.

Answer (score 4):

He wanted Luke to resist the dark side to be a jedi, and he feels that Luke isn't capable of resisting when Vader or Sideous tempt him(remember, Luke had just shown he wasn't even able to lift a x-wing with the force, meaning that he might be tempted by a chance to learn more easily)

> [Luke sees his X-Wing is about to sink into the bog]
> Luke: Oh, no! We'll never get it out now!
>
> Yoda: So certain, are you? Always with you, what cannot be done. Hear you nothing that I say?
>
> Luke: Master, moving stones around is one thing, but this is... totally different!
>
> Yoda: No! No different! Only different in your mind. You must unlearn what you have learned.
>
> Luke: All right, I'll give it a try.
>
> Yoda: No! Try not. Do... or do not. There is no try.
> [Luke tries to use the Force to levitate his X-Wing out of the bog, but fails in his attempt.]
>
> Luke: I can't. It's too big.
>
> Yoda: Size matters not. Look at me. Judge me by my size, do you? Hmm? Hmm. And well you should not. For my ally is the Force, and a powerful ally it is. Life creates it, makes it grow. Its energy surrounds us and binds us. Luminous beings are we, not this crude matter. You must feel the Force around you; here, between you, me, the tree, the rock, everywhere, yes. Even between the land and the ship.
>
> Luke: You want the impossible. [sees Yoda use the Force to levitate the X-Wing out of the bog and gets flustered when he does it] I don't... I don't believe it!
>
> Yoda: That is why you fail.

Therefore, Yoda thought that Luke shouldn't go. Yoda probably thought after he (Yoda himself that is) lost to Sidiuos. He probably then made the idea that to become a Jedi, someone needed to resist the dark side, or better yet defeat a sith..

> Yoda says: "You must confront Vader. Then,  only then, a Jedi will you be."

Therefore, after Luke comes back, Yoda sees he can handle a sith, therefor saying his training is complete.

Props to Darth Vader (the actual account person on this website) for suggesting the Resisting the dark side idea. Before it was all just defeating a sith.

Comment: Are you sure it has to do with fighting a Sith? What if he means you have to resist the Dark side first to become a Jedi?

Comment: Thats actually a really good idea. Im going to edit it and say resist the dark side. Are you okay with that. I'd cite you of course

Comment: Yes, it is fine. Thank you for citing me.

Comment: Also, I suggest capitalizing Sidious and also putting in that O there. I tend to be a grammar nazi when it comes to Star Wars spellings.

Answer (score 3):

Yoda and Obi-Wan wanted Luke to finish his training, but Luke would not stay since he wanted to go save his friends. The training he had not finished was his Force training, most likely, and controlling his emotions. Yoda thought Luke would fall to the dark side because of his emotions, as Anakin did before him. So, as you can tell, what Yoda was wanting was to teach Luke how to control his emotions. In Return of the Jedi, Luke has learned more about controlling the Force and controlling his emotions; I am certain he has learned to control his emotions, as because Luke fought Vader on Bespin and learnt his father was actually Vader, he seemed to handle his emotions well afterwards, as he hadn't fallen to the Dark side due to them.

Comment: Should've done it in first person. That'd make things more confusing.

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd Are you saying you _want_ me to make it confusing?

Comment: It would disrupt the Rebel's communications

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd this is a report from the Empire's own lieutenants and intelligence officers, so I don't think they would like their report being distorted

Comment: I removed the P.S. since my master said that the original PlayStation is outdated and should be removed :/

Comment: a communications disruption can only mean one thing! Invasion! 

oh wait, wrong sub